# IOC Container that can target .NET Framework Client Profile?

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control, .net-client-profile

On our current WPF project, we've been performing dependency injection using the Ninject IOC tool.

We want to target the .NET Framework Client Profile for a better download/install experience.  The problem is that Ninject seems to reference libararies such as System.Web which are NOT in the Client Profile.

Can anyone recommend an IOC container that can target the .NET Framework Client Profile (3.5 or 4) ?

Comment: Since the client profile is new, I'd guess that nobody who makes an IOC is targeting it just yet.  You could always grab the source of OS IOC libraries (such as Unity) set the targeting yourself and compile, fixing any errors.  Methinks any IOC targeting Web is using the Cache; the cache has been moved into the client framework IIRC so that would be easy to fix...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autofac supports both 3.5 and 4.0 Client Profile.

Answer (score 0):

Try really lightweight and simple [Funq](http://funq.codeplex.com/) DI container. It was initially created for the Mobile Application Blocks, so I believe it would be suitable for your purposes. (or at least idea of DI container on lambdas)